# Add global controller in Angular application

Tags: angularjs, controller, global, resolve

I have following scenario,

I have registers my files in $routeProvider as following way by using require.js

```
$routeProvider
               .when("/:Id", {
                   templateUrl: "Scripts/app/Views/MyHtml.html",
                   controller: "myController",
                   resolve: {
                       load: ['$q', '$rootScope', function ($q, $rootScope) {
                           var deferred = $q.defer();
                           require([
                               'scripts/app/controllers/myController', 
                           ], function () {
                               $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                                   deferred.resolve();
                               });

                           });
                           return deferred.promise;
                       }]
                   },
                   caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
               })...
....
..
```

Now I want to add my global controller in application module

I have this controller in different file.

```
(function () {
    app.controller("commonController", function ($rootScope, $scope){
        $scope.commonText = "You got successed."
    });
}())
```

Now I do not want to add commoncontroller file index.html, rather I want to resolve when my app.config execute.

I have done following code in $routeprovider function

```
var commonController = ['$q', '$rootScope', function ($q, $rootScope) {
               var deferred = $q.defer();
               require([
                   'scripts/app/commonController',
               ], function () {
                   $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                       deferred.resolve();
                   });
               });
               return deferred.promise;
           }]
```

But how do I resolve this commonController here.

Is there any way to resolve global controllers, directives, services for all common routes.

Thanks

Comment: You can't define additional controllers once the app has bootstrapped. (Not "legally")

Comment: Is there any other way to load common files in app.config?

Comment: Have a read at: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs